# Show that a function is increasing at a given interval

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, convex-analysis, graphing-functions

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9e3T8.jpg)So i have this function (integral) of
F(x)=integral tending from x(on top) to 0(on bottom) et² dt.

The question asks to show that the function is convex upward in [0, +∞).

How do i do that ? I was thinking of computing the integral with the boundaries. Then compute the derivative? I am not sure how to proceed.

Can somebody help ?

Comment: Hint : Calculate the derivate of the integral using the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: How to i calculate the deivative of the integral? should i compute first the integral with the boundaries and then compute the derivative of the result?

Comment: Can you quote the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus?

Comment: @SaraMartini Hi Sara. So the derivative of the integral is just your original function.

Comment: Okay,thanks! but what about the boundaries? Shouldn't i plug them in ? And what should i do to see if the function is concave upward in that integral? If you would be kind enought to tell me how to do the question step by step it would be really nice, because im kind of confused....

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Honestly,  why not just write down "The exponential is positive everywhere, including $[0,\infty]$. I mean, it's true.

Comment: The professor wants the maths explanatiion when solving the question ...

Comment: To decide whether a function is convex, you only need the second derivate.

Comment: @SaraMartini Okay, so I'm guessing he wants you to use the fundamental thm. of calc.

Comment: @Peter is right. The second derivative of the exponential...is positive. Because of earlier mentioned reasons about the exponential being positive everywhere. But yes, the prof wants fund. thm. of calc Peter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$F''(x)=(e^{x^2})'=2xe^{x^2}\geq0.$$

Comment: So the first derivative = e to the power of x squared. Then i compute the second derivative which equals 2xe to the power of x squared and see if it is greater than zero ... Correct?

Comment: And what about the boundaries of the integrals? Are they useless in this problem?

Comment: @Sara Martini Just $\left(\int\limits_a^xf(t)dt\right)'=f(x).$

Comment: So i only need to plug the first boundary?

Comment: I am sorry i really don't understand the boundaries use in this problme

Comment: @SaraMartini Then *please* write down the statement of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. Just once

Comment: I am looking at it now. it says to plug in the boundaries such that f(b)-f(a)

Comment: Maybe i got it. Simply put , according to the FTC the derivative of the integral is simply the integral WITHOUT TAKING INTO CONSIDERATION THE BOUNDARIES. Then to see if it is concave upward, i take the second derivative . Correct?

Comment: Yes, of course! In our case it's enough.